# Issue during VW T2 Volkswagen (10279) van assembly

Tags: vehicle

My build does not match [instructions](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6384271.pdf) on page 41:

[image]

When I place blue piece on top of the crossbar, there are spaces  on either side not one space. I have been extremely careful in following directions. What should I do?

Comment: Could you post a photo of what your model looks like before/after placing the blue 1 x 10 brick?

Comment: I am sorry. . .am new contributor & cannot figure out how to add photos. Normal copy/paste does not work and there doesn’t seem a way to access photos to choose them for porting over.

Comment: @PHom : does this meta FAQ help ? [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Thank you Sander, but I don’t have “10 reputation to embed images” and there is no picture button (to press) that shows anywhere on the screen. . .fyi, I’m on an iPad.

Comment: @PHom : just by virtue of asking this question, you have the reputation now. However, that button might indeed not be available on iPad as indicated in the answers to this question : [Is there any way to upload a screenshot from an iPad to this site (or other StackExchange sites)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/is-there-any-way-to-upload-a-screenshot-from-an-ipad-to-this-site-or-other-stac/2921). Those answers do however provide some alternatives, most involving somehow getting a url to the picture, or using a computer to add the picture.

Comment: If you're having difficulty, and have some other way of sharing the picture, please feel free to do so, and one of us will do the necessary to integrate it into your question.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED (“pilot error”). . .thanks everyone!!